# What is colon in a request uri?

Tags: java, micronaut

There is an endpoint written in a Micronaut application like so:

```
@Post("/{someId}:verb")
```

I want to make a POST request to it from POSTMAN but not sure how I hit that? So far I have tried:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/1234/verb // 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost:8080/1234:verb // this combines ':' with 1234 and that in turn fails that @Pattern validation that I have placed. 
POST http://localhost:8080/1234 // 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Comment: In your example you typed `vert`, not `verb`. Maybe that's why it fails?

Comment: sorry that was a type I fixed it

Comment: I expect the second one http://localhost:8080/1234:verb should match and your controller parameter someId would be set to 1234. Are you saying this does not happen? I dont see what Pattern validator you refer to. The default values are for variables, not URL's, I think. So :verb should just be a static part of URL here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting from the Micronaut documentation (*highlight added by me*):

> Remember that to **specify a default value** in a placeholder expression,
> you should use the colon `:` character, however if the default you are
> trying to specify has a colon then you should escape the value with
> back ticks.

So probably you need to replace the `verb` by a default value, if `someId` is not set.

When `someId` is provided in your POST request, the method will use `someId`. Otherwise it will use the default value, which is `verb` as per your example. So if you are testing with POSTMAN, either set the id or leave it empty, to test the default value.

Comment: User I tried that also. When I do that, I get `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Then check your URI, the path looks incomplete.

Comment: What is your controller called like? Something like `http://localhost:8080/book/1234`, for instance, if you have a `BookController`. If you leave out the `1234`, a default book will be returned, e.g. book #5 in case you defined (`@Post("/{someId}:5")`).

Comment: I understand very well the concept of ':' in respect to injecting default values etc. For some reason, it's not working and it just returns those error codes that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: In `@Post("/{someId}:verb")` the `:` is outside of the curly braces.  I don't think it is a default value delimiter.

Comment: I see, should be `${someId:5}` for expressions with a default value then. Then `:verb` is probably just a static part of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question (--> You aren't looking for a default value for someId?), but the following code works for me with cURL (`someId` can be a String or Integer - what you prefer more):

```java
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.PathVariable;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller("/")
public class DemoController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoController.class);

    @Post(value = "/{someId}:verb", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String postMethod(@PathVariable String someId) {
        String message = "You called me with the value: " + someId;
        logger.info(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

cURL:

```
.\curl.exe -X POST http://localhost:8080/WeLoveCake42:verb
.\curl.exe -X POST http://localhost:8080/12345678:verb
```

Output:

```
20:14:42.027 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] INFO  com.example.DemoController - You called me with the value: WeLoveCake42
20:15:37.989 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] INFO  com.example.DemoController - You called me with the value: 12345678
```

In case I misunderstood your question:

- I had no luck using the `defaultValue` on `@PathVariable`
- I had no luck making the value `someId` `@Nullable`

I guess the routing/dispatcher is not flexible enough to detect this pattern (Maybe it might even lead to a non-determinstic behaviour, so it's quite understandable).